# Yarn não inicia servidor de desenvolvimento

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, npm, yarn

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um site com react, mas ao usar o dar o comando `yarn start`, ele não incia o meu servidor.

[image: print do CMDER com com o comando yarn start]

Comment: fez um `yarn run build` antes? não tem erro, tem certeza que o codigo está nessa pasta para o yarn fazer start corretamente? me parece que não tem nada para iniciar....

Comment: Fiz sim, e essa é a pasta raiz do meu projeto.

Comment: Não publique código como imagem código deve ser publicado como texto. [Referência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se sua pasta de arquivos está configurada normalmente o index. Depois,
o arquivo package.json provavelmente está correto porque ele chamou o `$ react-scrips start`. Sendo assim, tenta excluir node_modules, yarn.lock e package-lock.json e depois reinstalar novamente seus pacotes.

Comment: Fiz isso, porém continuo com o mesmo problema!

Comment: Se você iniciar um novo projeto com `npx create-react-app project-name` e tentar usar o `yarn start` ele funciona?